What "Space 1999" episode was this?
Wanted to ask about a particular episode of Space: 1999 (a British sci-fi TV series from 1970's) that I recall (partially) seeing as a child.
This was an episode in which the crew of Moonbase Alpha battled an enemy that had ships or tanks that looked circular (if I remember correctly they rolled on the surface of the moon sort of like a tire would).
What episode would this have been?

This one, from The Taybor? http://catacombs.space1999.net/main/models/w2mtayborgun.html
